# How to get fontawesome to work on angular app

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome

This is insane. For the better part of the last three hours I have been trying to use ANY font awesome symbol other than the fa-plus but to no avail.

Code:

```
<!-- This works -->
<button *ngIf="queries.length < 3"
        class="btn slick_button float-start col-1"
        (click)="add_query()">
    <i class="fa-sharp fa-light fa-plus fa-beat-fade fa-2xl" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);"></i>
</button>

<!-- This does not (for fa-minus or any other sumbol that SHOULD be there) -->
<button *ngIf="queries.length < 3"
        class="btn slick_button float-start col-1"
        (click)="add_query()">
    <i class="fa-sharp fa-light fa-minus fa-beat-fade fa-2xl" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);"></i>
</button>
```

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/@fontawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css"
            ],
```

package.json:
`"@fontawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0"`

Linking it as a stylesheet in index.html didn't help either.

What am I missing? How come one sumbol works but not any other?!

Comment: tutorial: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: You have to declare the `font-family` as such where you're using it (the fontawesome angular fork npm Jordy listed above isn't necessary)....when you inspect the css does for your `i` elements that use it does it have `font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Free'` and can you access the css file externally to ensure the references are available?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I believe you are using the package `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free`, because there is not package in npm called `@fontawesome/fontawesome-free`.

Well after playing around it seems like the package `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` you have installed is not like the original fontawesome, it does not by default include all the icons in the file `fontawesome.css`. You need to use `all.css` to have all the icons. In your `angular.json` replace:

`"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css"`

with:

`"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"`

**Update**

If you are only using the free version, then only solid and brand packages are available. So you also need to change your classes from `fa-sharp` to `fa-solid`.

> Font Awesome Sharp requires Pro and specific versions!
> Make sure you have an active Pro-level plan or a Pro license with access to the specific versions that include Sharp's styles.

Here is a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mq5c77?file=src/main.ts

Comment: That didn't work. I got this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome to work, but it only has the solid pack on it and needs .ts code overhead as well. Oh well..

Comment: I still don't get why the plus sign works. But I 've stopped asking questions at this point.

Comment: well when you are using the free version only solid and brand are available https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts#reference-font-awesome-in-your-project

Comment: There was a typing mistake in my answer. I've corrected `@fontawesome` to `@fortawesome`

Comment: I have updated my solution and posted a working example.

Comment: Why it did work with fa-sharp we could look for an explaination. But I fontawesome documentation does not include the sharp in the free version, so there is nothing to wonder if any magic happens.